# Rewrite Rules - httpd.conf

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache

I have the following entry in the `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.anotherdomain.uk.com/ [L,R=302]
</VirtualHost>
```

I would look to arrange this such that when entering `www.mydomain.com/admin` I will not get redirected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.mydomain.com

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/admin
     RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.anotherdomain.uk.com/ [L,R=302]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I cannot confirm this yet ... I will reply soon coz the hosting provider is saying it did not work. Thanks for the reply.